# Google Mobile Vision library not downloading in some android devices

Tags: java, android, face-detection

I am using Google Mobile Vision Library for Face Detection, It is working fine in some devices but in some devices i am getting Mobile vision library not downloading issue. I have enough storage and updated Google Play Services with SD card also.

One more thing, when i restart these devices than it will work perfectly and library downloaded successfully but i want to instant download after app installation  and i an using below mentioned dependency

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'

I had Google more times but i did not get solution.So please help me.

Thanks

Comment: anyone have solution for this issue...

Comment: did you find any solution for that? I have the same problem, thanks.